# cartopy: import cartopy.crs error

Tags: python, python-xarray, cartopy, rasterio

I'm working on some development for `xarray`. I was trying to install `rasterio` but it seems to have messed up my `cartopy` installation.

I installed `rasterio` on my mac using:

```
brew install gdal
pip install rasterio
```

Now when I try `import cartopy.crs as ccrs` I get the error

```
Invalid argument (must be a Polygon)
Geometry must be a Point or LineString
Assertion failed: (0 != cs), function GEOSCoordSeq_getSize_r, file geos_ts_c.cpp, line 3991.
Abort trap: 6
```

Possibly something with the paths/versions of `GEOS`, `PROJ4` or `GDAL` changed?

Is there a way to do a clean installation of `cartopy` which will grab the dependencies?

I originally installed `cartopy` using `conda install -c conda-forge cartopy`. Doing `conda update cartopy` doesn't really do anything as I have the latest version.

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I do a large portion of my work with cartopy.

Edit: some discussion about this here https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/612

`$ geos-config --version`
`3.6.2`

Tried

```
conda remove xarray cartopy rasterio gdal geos proj4 shapely
conda install -c conda-forge xarray cartopy rasterio gdal geos proj4 shapely
```

but to no avail

Comment: Have you tied installing `gda`l and `rasterio` from conda as well? You should be able to get all the dependencies you need with `conda install -c conda-forge xarray cartopy rasterio gdal ...` and conda should be able to find the right combination of libraries/versions. My experience is that mixing brew/pip/conda can lead to problems.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't get the `conda install` working with `rasterio` so I went down the other mac installation path, although now I'm paying for it. Unfortunately, the new `conda install` didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cartopy` was picking up the `geos` directory from the `brew install gdal`. I therefore removed this using:

```
$ brew tap beeftornado/rmtree
$ brew rmtree gdal
$ brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies proj
$ brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies geos
$ brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies json-c
$ brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies freexl
$ brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies liblwgeom
```

`cartopy` then correctly picked up the `geos` directory which is installed during the `conda` installation of `cartopy`.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.